# Target Packages problem during apt-get update

Tags: package-management, updates

I get this error during `apt-get update`:

```
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:2
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:2
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:2
    W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:2
    W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:2
    W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:2
    W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:2
    W: Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8123 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
    W: Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8123:
    W: Failed to fetch http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8123:
    W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/InRelease  Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8123 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
    W: Failed to fetch https://download.sublimetext.com/apt/stable/InRelease  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8123: Connection refused
    W: Failed to fetch https://ftp.ussg.iu.edu/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu/xenial/InRelease  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8123: Connection refused
    W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8123 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
    W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/george-edison55/cmake-3.x/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8123:
    W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8123 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
    W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8123:
    W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/apps/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8123:
    W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8123:
    W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/persepolis/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8123:
    W: Failed to fetch http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/xenial-pgdg/InRelease  Could not connect to 127.0.0.1:8123 (127.0.0.1). - connect (111: Connection refused)
    W: Failed to fetch https://repo.skype.com/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8123: Connection refused
    W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/smathot/cogscinl/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8123:
    W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/umang/indicator-stickynotes/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8123:
    W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:2
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:2
    W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:2
    W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:2
    W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:2
    W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:2
    W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list:2
```

and `etc/apt/sources.list` is like this :

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
## team.
deb http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://ir.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
# deb-src https://download.sublimetext.com/ apt/stable/
deb https://ftp.ussg.iu.edu/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/
# deb-src https://ftp.ussg.iu.edu/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/
```

what is the problem?

**UPDATE:**
I found the problem but i don't know how to solve it .the problem is apt-get is using proxy and i did not use any proxy anywhere. i don't know which `conf` file is used by apt-get

Comment: Carefully read the first line only. Remove the duplication that it is telling you about. Then read the second line only. Rinse and repeat until all the duplicates are gone. In the future, stop adding the same sources repeatedly.

Comment: You listed your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, but package management also use files within sources.list.d/  (on a fresh install this directory is empty - they are added by users of the system post-install) - most of your errors are in these files, ie. user(s) of your system added things twice (didn't check if something was already there, just added it again anyway).  You need to reverse these as user535733 stated  (or duplicate link)

Comment: @karel i test third answer of link and give me "check your internet connection" error